# Create VCF file with "PHOTO" imported using URL linking to an image file

Tags: vcf-vcard

I'm trying to create a .VCF file according to these specs (using version 3.0)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VCard#vCard_3.0

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2426#section-3.1.4

It all works fine unless the PHOTO field.

If I try to set the PHOTO using an external image (using the URI value) there is no way to have my mac or android to import the image to the created contact.

```
PHOTO;VALUE=URI;TYPE=GIF:http://www.example.com/dir_photos/my_photo.gif
```

It works if I embed base64 code on the JPG file.

Thank you. Has anyone succeded?

Answer (score 4):

You need to include a base64 encoded image uri:

```
PHOTO;ENCODING=BASE64;TYPE=PNG:iVBORw0KG...
```